# I need help to copy content between two headings in word - vba

Tags: vba, cpu-word

I need help in 3 VBA in word.
First: to copy the title of heading X
Second: to copy between heading X to X+1
Third to go to the new heading

I need to transform my headings in a question and answer game in another software. So I would like to automate

For example

HeadStyle 1: Question 1: aaaaa?

Head Style 2: ans
Head Style 2: ans
no style text:ans

HeadStyle 1: Question 2: bbbb?
Head Style 2: ans
Head Style 2: ans
no style text: ans

I want first to select current heading: "Question 1: aaaaa?" then copy --- after that I'll paste with autohotkey to another software.
Then, I would like to copy the answer:
Head Style 2: ans
Head Style 2: ans
no style text: ans

Then to repeat the process I would like to select next heading with headstyle 1: Question 2: bbbb?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44971-vba-copy-content-heading.html and http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67382-I-need-help-to-copy-content-between-two-headings-in-word-vba. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: Excelguru Help Site - A message to forum cross posters

Comment: it is a different forum, what is the problem?